# Is it legal to upgrade to 200 A service yourself?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I live in Markham, Ontario and I am the owner and resident of a house with 100A service. I know it might be a complicated and dangerous job but I would like to know if I can legally perform the upgrade to 200A myself if I acquire all permits.

From what I know there are some main steps involved:

0. Get a permit (Is this a separate process from getting inspected?)
1. Fill an application for service upgrade with my utility company.
2. Request a disconnect on the day of the job
3. Replace wires, main panel and probably meter base.
4. Get the job inspected on the same day
5. Request service connect

I really want to know what can stop me from doing it myself.
Also it would be extremely helpful if you guys have any tips, good-to-know points, etc for me.
Thanks

Comment: If it is a separated single family home, then usually yes.  Your locality might have different regulations saying no.  The question you need to ask yourself is should you.  The work is not that difficult, but codes have changed enough so it might not be just copying the work that is there now.  Be prepared for the work not going as fast as you think, if inspector does not sign off, they usually need to be reschedule for another day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This varies by jurisdiction. Some jurisdictions allow homeowners to do minor work but not major work (and a heavyup is major work). Some will allow homeowners to do major work but only after passing an exam of some sort. And some will allow homeowners to do everything. Check with your local jurisdiction (the office that issues electrical permits) to find out.

Whether you do this yourself or with an electrician, I recommend installing the new panel and moving most of the circuits, if possible, prior to the official switchover day. That minimizes the time you are without power, which is important for your refrigerator.

As far as the sequence of inspection, reconnect, etc., it can vary a lot. In some places the electrician (or homeowner if that is allowed) is able to reconnect the meter and the inspection comes later (within a few days) and the utility comes back later to replace the line from the meter to the street (obviously this is based on a reasonable assumption that you won't be running at 160A the day after doing your heavy-up).

While, generally speaking, most code changes are *not* required to be retrofitted as part of a heavy-up, such as adding AFCI and GFCI protection to existing circuits, two things that often come into play are:

- Meter Base vs. Meter Main

This varies by jurisdiction and utility. You must use a meter base or meter main that your jurisdiction and utility approve. These are often (at least a year or two ago) in short supply and variances from the usual list may or may not be approved. NEC 2020 requires an outside disconnect, which is typically done using a meter main, but not all areas have adopted NEC 2020 and even where they have there may be local exceptions to this particular rule. You need to find out before you get started.

- Ground Rods

Making sure the grounding is good goes along with a heavy-up. If the existing grounding is not up to current standards then you may need to upgrade it. Typically that is some combination of a water main ground and one or two ground rods. Even if code in your area has not changed, the existing grounding may not be intact and may need to be replaced.

Comment: CEC will be the applicable (but largely similar, except where it's not) code for Markham, Ontario, Canada.

Comment: Thanks for the through explanation. Do I need to replace meter base if it's already 200A? I can read on the meter that's 240v and 200A

Comment: That will be up to your utility. Mine (Pepco) required a new meter base, which to be honest, I agreed with as the old one was quite old, and feed wires (street to house from Pepco, top of house to meter base and meter base to panel from my electrician) even though the meter itself is the same 200A meter that Pepco put in many years ago when they switched to smart meters.

Answer (score 3):

In the vast, vast majority of cases, a person who owns and occupies their home and isn't planning to sell it (sorry flippers) is allowed to do their own electrical work without restriction.   *You do need permits and inspections, just the same*.

And there's the problem. AHJs generally will not permit an unworkable plan.  "Replace wires, main panel and meter pan, all in the same day" is *awfully optimistic*. The AHJ is likely to see it that way, and ask where you plan to be sleeping that night.  So I like plans that are unlikely to fail.

You are correct that you will need a new meter pan.  As well as a new mast for size, possibly new service entrance conduit for size, and certainly a new main panel as I doubt your existing is 200A ready.  Basically nothing is reusable; it's a total re-do.

So one of my favorite tricks (not always possible in an excessively finished house) is to build the new stuff *right next to* the old stuff. Put a new 200A panel next to the existing panel.  Wire it up so it is a subpanel of the existing panel with 100A feeder wire. The supply breaker in the old main panel: size doesn't matter - only needs to be able to fit the 100A wires. E.G. #3 copper on a 60A breaker is a good fit.  Leave yourself lots of slack.  At the 200A panel, don't feed the 200A main breaker up top -- install a 100A breaker in the branch circuit area and *backfeed it*. This may require a tie-down kit.

At your leisure, in the original panel, obtain an accessory ground bar or two (recommended model numbers are on the panel label) and move all your grounds to those bars.

At this point, you have an empty 200A *subpanel* being back-fed via a 100A breaker. No load is in it, and nothing is connected to the 200A main terminals. With me so far?

Now, coming off those 200A main terminals, run new service wire to your 200A meter pan, riser and weatherhead.

What does cutover day look like?  Simplicity itself.  The power company moves the service drop to the new weatherhead, installs the new meter.  Now, the 200A panel is the main, and the 100A panel is the subpanel; the feeder simply reverses direction. Now I bet the feed breaker in the old main did not have a tie-down kit, so you'll need to move the feeder wires to the old main breaker input.  But that's a victory lap if you left yourself the wire length.

The old service wires, meter pan, riser and weatherhead are demolished. Use the old service pass-thru for EV charging :)

Now what if the old panel is a dangerous old thing and you want to replace it?  It's a subpanel now, so it can be fully de-energized and you can work safely.

What if you want the old panel *to go away* because you don't like the clutter? OK, move all the circuits one at a time to the new panel.  This can be done one circuit at a time, at your leisure: it doesn't need to be a Big Project Day.  You'll want plenty of breaker spaces in the new panel for that; don't consider less than a 40-space panel.